# US income tax for non US citizen

Tags: united-states, income-tax, google

If I sell In App Purchases ANDROID to US customers from outside USA do I have to pay income tax to USA.Google already taxes a 30% cut.

Comment: Please add more details and elaborate your question with real examples. In general,  US Sourced Income will need to pay taxes to IRS but a US customer is not a source of income.

Comment: If I launch an app on play store  US customers may buy  In App Purchases from my app. After this Google will remit slaes tax in US and  also take a 30% cut and pay me.

Comment: In this case should I pay through IRS.

Comment: I am currently not residing in     US and have              never been there.

Comment: Anyone please answer.

Comment: I am basically selling services to the US.

Comment: You say that Google will remit tax in the US; can you explain exactly what tax are they remitting and how it's calculated? You may have to look at the agreement you have with them (or post a link to it if it's online).

Comment: They take 30% service charge and remit sales tax.

Comment: I understand about the service charge, but what exactly is the "sales tax" that they remit, to who exactly do they remit it and what at what rate do they calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not have to pay income tax to the US if you aren't a tax resident of the US.
You likely will have to pay income tax in the country you live and/or your country of citizenship.

Answer (score 1):

You know, the whole Idea around the payment services like Google store, Apple store, ShareIt, ... is to save you all the hassle of international taxation. 
You get you money from google India and google resales your products, with correct taxation (VAT, mainly) to the customers around the world. 
You only have to worry about the correct declaration of your income in India.